# SpringBootAdmin cluster configuration behind a load balancer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, microservices, spring-boot-admin

SpringBootAdmin looks very useful for our team for a particular use case. I have tried it and got cluster configuration working on my local machine.

However, when I deployed it to our development environment, it's not working and showing the client instances as offline. In Dev environment, we have 2 instances of SpringBootAdmin running behind a load balancer.

Has anyone been able to make it work with multiple instances in a clustered config behind a load balancer?
Also, are there any plans for it to support Redis?

Thanks!